# Outlook.Mailitem failed to be called by another sub

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to save the attachments of an email to my desktop. A sub calls another sub using the Item(1) as input. So far I have this, it gives error when calling the sub saveAttachtoDisk. It gives the error shown on the picture.

```
Sub Call_saveAttachtoDisk()

Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
Dim objMsg As Object 'Object

Set objSelection = ActiveExplorer.Selection

Set objMsg = objSelection.Item(1)

saveAttachtoDisk (objMsg)

End Sub

Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
     Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
     Dim saveFolder As String
     Dim i As Integer

     i = 0
     saveFolder = "C:\Users\peet\Desktop"
     For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
          i = i + 1
          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\name" & i & ".pdf"
          Set objAtt = Nothing
     Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This is not the error for which you are seeking help but it will cause problems later.  Images and signatures can be attachments.  You are saving every attachment with an extension of XLS regardless of its original extension.  XLS is the extension for an Excel 2003 workbook.  Are you really still using Excel 2003?  Since 2007, the normal extensions for a workbook are XLSX or XLSM.

Comment: @TonyDallimore actually I'm saving .pdf attachments.

Comment: I see the correction to your code.  However, this does not change the main point: you should save a file with its original extension.  If an attachment is an image, for example, it will have an extension of PNG or BMP or similar.  If you change that extension to PDF, the wrong program will try to open it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

Need to add `Call` before calling the sub

`Call saveAttachtoDisk (objMsg)`

Answer (score 0):

*Simply remove the parenthesis* **`()`**

*Exmple*

> ```
> saveAttachtoDisk objMsg
> ```